# Datadog: how to trigger a notification when a new DD_VERSION is detected by APM?

Tags: version, monitoring, datadog, apm, datadog-dashboard

I'm using Datadog APM, exporting the version / tag when I'm deploying a new container:

DD_VERSION=x.y.z

Further information on this [link](https://docs.datadoghq.com/getting_started/tagging/unified_service_tagging/?tab=ecs)

Now, quite simply, is there a way to create an event or "alert" when a new version is being updated?

[image: Total Requests by Version]

The dashboard is using: `trace.web.request.hits.as_counts` but I can't find the way to add this notification.

Thanks!